# Change SASS or LESS variable value at runtime

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, sass, less

I am actually trying to make a web app using ASP MVC to support some dynamic color setting. For example, admin can set theme colors for specific user groups. When admin saves the new color codes, those new color codes need to be saved in CSS. So users login they will see different colors based on their group.

For this, I am thinking of using SASS or LESS. It would be easier if I can easily set variables in SASS or LESS to new color codes in Save action.

So my questions is...

1. How can I retrieve variables from SASS or LESS file and set new value to the variables? Is there a library for this? I have checked BundleTransformer and dotless. But I still don't know if these library support handling variables.
2. If I can update variables in SASS or LESS, will it be compiled on any change?
   And what can I do for the cached CSS on client side?
3. I would really appreciate it if you guys can give me any better or other approaches.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting only users with modern browsers, CSS has experimental variable support (see [Can I use..](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) data). Here's an example of from MDN:

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: pink;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

If you took this approach, you would only have to insert the colour variable into a simple stylesheet, and CSS would do the rest:

```
<style>
:root {
  --group-colour: {{ groupColour }}
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/stylesheet/with/variables.css">
```

For more information on CSS variables, see MDN's [CSS `var()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know css supports variables.